# Print bytes as longlong

Tags: c++, windows, msdn

I have a void pointer pointing to a block of 196 bytes. I need to print the contiguous bytes as LONGLONG(__int64) values. I am using following block to print, but observing a crash in the application.
What am i doing wrong? 
Is there a better way of doing this?

```
        LONGLONG* llx = 0;
        void *ptr = evt.MofData;
        for (int i = 0; i < evt.MofLength; i += 8)
        {
            llx = reinterpret_cast<LONGLONG*>(ptr);
            sprintf_s(msgbuf, "szof(LL[%d]), val[%ll]\n ", sizeof(LONGLONG), (*llx));
            OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
            llx = (LONGLONG *)llx + 1;
        }
```

Comment: 1) `196 % 64 != 0`, 2) in the first line of the `for` loop you overwrite `llx`, so the last line `llx = ... + 1;` does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `memcpy`:

```
constexpr std::size_t length = 196;
constexpr std::size_t n_blocks = length / sizeof(LONGLONG);
LONGLONG llx[n_blocks];
std::memcpy(llx, ptr, n_blocks * sizeof(LONGLONG));
```

Now you can read `LONGLONG`s from the `llx` array.

If the `length` is not a compile-time constant, you can use `std::vector`:

```
const std::size_t length = get_length();    // not a compile-time constant
const std::size_t n_blocks = length / sizeof(LONGLONG);
std::vector<LONGLONG> llx(n_blocks);
std::memcpy(llx.data(), ptr, n_blocks * sizeof(LONGLONG));
```

Also, the type specifier for a value returned by `sizeof` [should be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019) `%zu` or `%Iu`, not `%d`. And for `long long` it should be `%lld`.